# How to show localstorage data in HTML form using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am saving data in localstorage temporary, because of user have to go to another page before submit the form, But i have problem to display data in form again.

Here is my code

```
$('#ip_range').click(function(e) {
     var data = $('#Demoform').serializeArray();
    // localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(data));
     var formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData'));
     $.each(formData, function(i, val) {
        var data = $("input[name='"+val.name+"']").val(val.value);
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

This is the json data that i want to display

```
[{
        "name": "timezone",
        "value": "America/New_York"
    }, {
        "name": "fiscal_year",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "first_day",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "highest_level",
        "value": "393"
    }, {
        "name": "company_administrator",
        "value": "393"
    }, {
        "name": "ip_restrictions",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "ip_range",
        "value": "4"
    }, {
        "name": "languages_enabled",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "language",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "enable_single_sign",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "user_sign_off",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "widgets_sort_order",
        "value": "Links,Training,Task"
    }, {
        "name": "confirm",
        "value": "1"
    }]
```

Comment: What is the problem? We need details about what is/is not happening, along with what should happen and any error messages you get

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is no error, i just want to display in form

Comment: Ok, so again, what's the problem?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nothing display in form

Comment: Have you checked the contents of localStorage? What does `data` contain? Where are you setting localStorage? You're not making it very easy for anyone to help you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan check updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close here, but this part `$("input[name='"+val.name+"']").val(val.value)` is what I think your problem is. Try the code below. I think this is what you are trying to do.

I would structure the input like such: `var data = $('<input name="'+ val.name +'" value="'+ val.value +'" />');`

I'd put a stack snippet up, but it doesn't work well with `localStorage`, so click on the jsfiddle link and click the IP Range button to see the form get the inputs with the proper names.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ygh8pdk1/

```
var data = [
    {
      "name": "timezone",
      "value": "America/New_York"
    }, {
      "name": "fiscal_year",
      "value": "1"
    }, {
      "name": "first_day",
      "value": "0"
    }, {
      "name": "highest_level",
      "value": "393"
    }, {
      "name": "company_administrator",
      "value": "393"
    }, {
      "name": "ip_restrictions",
      "value": "1"
    }, {
      "name": "ip_range",
      "value": "4"
    }, {
      "name": "languages_enabled",
      "value": "0"
    }, {
      "name": "language",
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "name": "enable_single_sign",
      "value": "0"
    }, {
      "name": "user_sign_off",
      "value": "0"
    }, {
      "name": "widgets_sort_order",
      "value": "Links,Training,Task"
    }, {
      "name": "confirm",
      "value": "1"
    }
];

localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(data));

$('#ip_range').click(function(e) {
  var formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData'));
  $.each(formData, function(i, val) {
    var data = $('<input name="'+ val.name + '" value="'+ val.value +'" />');
    $('#form-data').append(data);
  });
});
```